# ValueError: could not convert string to float : bored

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Here's my data frame.

```
    tag         score
0   hiding      63.0
1   windowsill  1.0
2   porch       1.0
3   deck        1.0
4   bored       1.0
```

I'm trying to plot score against tag.

```
tag_df = pd.DataFrame(list(tag_map.items()), columns=['tag', 'score'])
plt.plot(tag_df['tag'], tag_df['score'], color='blue')
```

I get the following error,

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'bored'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is `autotag_map`?

Comment: It's a hashmap from which I'm obtaining the data frame.

Comment: I've update the code to include the matplotlib line.

Comment: I think you do not understand what you are wanting. Strings have no intrinsic numerical value to plot. I think what you really want is just a plot of score at some fixed spacing (e.g. the integer index) with the appropriate *labels* from tag. There's plenty of info in matplotlib and pandas on manipulating tick labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.plot.bar(x='tag', y='score', rot=0)
```

[image]

Here is [a great Pandas Visualisation tutorial with tons of examples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html)

Comment: This actually works. Can you please explain your answer why this worked and why the previous one didn't. Also in this syntax where is plt, as in how am I accessing matplotlib without using the plt variable. Is this even using matplotlit?

Comment: @MelissaStewart see the documentation for [`pandas.Dataframe.plot()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot)

Comment: @MelissaStewart, this is a standard way to plot in Pandas. Please read the [tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) - i don't think i can explain it any better

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial and I was scanning through it. There's one fundamental thing I can't seem to understand. I'm importing `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` How can i access `matplotlib` without that variable.

Comment: @MelissaStewart, AFAIK `DataFrame.plot()` does it for you. You just have to execute `plt.show()` at the end of your script/program. I'm using interactive Python (ipython) - it has "magic" commands like `%matplotlib`. After that i can plot by executing literally one command: `df.plot(...)`